# Flask returns 404 when sending file

Tags: python, flask

The path is correct, and the file exists.

```
@app.route('/Users/<username>/<filename>')
def send_image(username, filename):
    return send_from_directory('/Users/'+username, filename)
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /myuploads HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/1185392_716316861727493_1066399254_n.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/boy.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/gg.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/IMG_1409.PNG HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/IMG_2743.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/IMG_2757.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2017 20:29:00] "GET /Users/alon123/secondpage.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Here is the directory structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M5wm.png)

The root is Ludbox, and the html that call the function mentioned above could be found in templates.

Comment: The code should work, can you share the directory structure, from the root directory.

Comment: @PEJK I have added the directory stracture to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward slash to the endpoint:

```
@app.route('/Users/<username>/<filename>/')
```